# How to scale website to iPhone's width?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, mobile, viewport

I've got liquid layout website that displays (8 x 240px) columns on 1920x1080px. There are no spaces between them. I added this to HEAD:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes,width=960" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
```

I tried different settings in above code but no matter what I do on iPhone 2G and 4S it always displays (4 x 240px) columns (480×320px and 960x640px resolutions).

I want it to display 3 or 2 columns because first column contain text and it's hardly readable now.

**I just want to divide width by two on iPhone. How can this be done?**

Furthermore, my website displays differently on iPhone (480x320px) and on desktop when I make browser 480x320px. Why is that?

Comment: What you are looking for is called Responsive Web Design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design

Comment: That's right but this doesn't answer my questions why above solution doesn't work. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Ok, here is two great links about `meta viewport`; https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag and http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

Comment: Thank you! I think that's going to resolve this issue because it seems to be comprehensive :) I'll read that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven´t used `meta viewport` before but it seems strange to set it twice and why use semicolon `;` in one and commas `,` in the other?

This seems more right to me but I haven´t tested it;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes,width=960" />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works but without initial-scale: 1 :) And I set width to 800.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to use jquery to switch the viewport setting depending on screen size.

```
if($(window).width() >= 768) {
    // Change viewport for smaller devices
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=959');
}
```